# $httpBackend.flush(); causes Karma to fail

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When I run `grunt jasmine` all my specs pass, but when I run `grunt karma` Karma basically silently fails since "Warning: Task 'karma:unit' failed. Use --force to continue. Aborted due to warnings." tells me close to nothing. If I remove all of my $httpBackend checks then `grunt karma` passes again. It almost seems to occur when I add the `flush()` method.

Both Angular and Angular-Mocks are on 1.2.26.

**Does anyone know why my unit tests are failing in Karma and not in Jasmine?**

```
'use strict';

describe('DashboardCtrl spec', function() {

  var $scope,
      $route,
      $controller,
      $httpBackend;

  // Load the services's module
  beforeEach(module('LocalStorageModule'));
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$route_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $route = _$route_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    $httpBackend.expectGET('//localhost:8081/api1/api/things1/').respond({});
    $httpBackend.expectGET('//localhost:8081/api1/api/things2/').respond({
      'next': 'somepage.html'
    });
    $httpBackend.expectGET('views/dashboard.html').respond('<p></p>');
    $controller('DashboardCtrl', {$scope: $scope, $route: { current: { params: ''}}});
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  describe('$scope.init()', function() {

    it('Check $scope assignments.', function() {
      expect($scope.displayLoadContainer).toBe(true);
    });

  });

});



// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2014-09-16 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    preprocessors: {
      'app/scripts/controllers/dashboard.js': 'coverage'
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/tp-utils/app/scripts/services/tp-utils.js',
      'bower_components/angular-local-storage/angular-local-storage.js',
      'bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js',
      'bower_components/tp-services/dist/tp-services.js',

      'app/scripts/app.js',
      'app/scripts/api-dev.js',
      'app/scripts/controllers/dashboard.js',

      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-coverage'
    ],

    reporters: ['coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'text',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    },

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what browsers do you have set Karma to test with?

Comment: I think we need to see your relevant `karma.conf.js` file.

Comment: Just Phantom. I was able to go in and add 'progress' to the reporters...I was only using 'coverage'. When I did that Karma started giving me more detailed/helpful output. I still don't understand why grunt jasmine was passing though when Karma was blowing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that your Unit Tests are wrong. You can't have expectations inside a `beforeEach` function. I think that what you want to do is something like this:

```
describe('DashboardCtrl spec', function() {
  var $scope,
      $route,
      $controller,
      $httpBackend;

  // Load the services's module
  beforeEach(module('LocalStorageModule'));
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$route_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $route = _$route_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', '//localhost:8081/api1/api/things1/').respond({});
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '//localhost:8081/api1/api/things2/').respond({
      'next': 'somepage.html'
    });
    var createController = function(){
      $controller('DashboardCtrl', {$scope: $scope, $route: { current: { params: ''}}});
    }
  }));

  describe('$scope.init()', function() {

    it('Check $scope assignments.', function() {
      createController();
      $httpBackend.flush();
      $scope.$digest();
      expect($scope.displayLoadContainer).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Josep. I had actually come up with something fairly similar. Its nice to be able call controllers within your it() statements. Unfortunately however, this doesn't solve the issue of why jasmine was passing while Karma was failing.